# Changing the image as if I click on a another image just as in shopping site

Tags: reactjs

I have some image as shown below. Some of them are small images and some of them are large. I wanted to implement the same functionality as in the shopping sites that when a user clicks on smallImage then the UI will display the corresponding large Image of that small Image. So far I have come up this **MainCode**.please help me in this. Thanks in advance

```
                             smallImage: [
                                            {
                                                id: 11111,
                                                smallImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/19800763/resize-h56-w56%5Ecompr-r50/9433/94334845/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11112,
                                                smallImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/59637694/resize-h56-w56%5Ecompr-r50/9435/94357311/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11113,
                                                smallImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/25218820/resize-h56-w56%5Ecompr-r50/9435/94357298/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11114,
                                                smallImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/70832165/resize-h56-w56%5Ecompr-r50/9435/94357307/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11115,
                                                smallImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/89686883/resize-h56-w56%5Ecompr-r50/9435/94357327/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        largeImage: [
                                            {
                                                id: 11111,
                                                largeImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/95847441/resize-h800-w800%5Ecompr-r85/9433/94334845/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11112,
                                                largeImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/19681398/resize-h800-w800%5Ecompr-r85/9435/94357311/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg", 
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11113,
                                                largeImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/90429384/resize-h800-w800%5Ecompr-r85/9435/94357298/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11114,
                                                largeImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/08486927/resize-h800-w800%5Ecompr-r85/9435/94357307/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                id: 11115,
                                                largeImage: "https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/89632209/resize-h800-w800%5Ecompr-r85/9435/94357327/Corwin+Convertible+Sleeper.jpg",
                                            }
                                        ],
```

**MainCode**

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react'

import "./individual-item.styles.css"
import { ShopProductsContext } from "../../context/shopProducts/shopProductsContext"
import Heading from "../Heading/heading.component"

export default function IndividualItem({ match, location: {state} }) {

    const { products, dispatch } = useContext(ShopProductsContext)
    const [largeImage, setLargeImage] = useState(state.item[0].largeImage)

    const getLargeImage = (image) => {
        setlargeImage.filter(largeImg => {
           return largeImg.id === image.id
         })
    } 
    return ( 
        <div className="containe-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-7">
                    <div className="individual-item-left-container">
                        <div className="individual-item-big-img-container text-center">
                            {largeImage.map(img => (
                                <img src={img.largeImage} alt="product"/>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        <div className="small-image-container">
                            {state.item[0].smallImage.map(img => (
                               <img onClick={() => getLargeImage(img)} key={img.id} className="mx-3" src={img.smallImage} alt="small product"/>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem/issue?

Comment: I wanted a display the large image when I click on the small image just as same in the shopping site

Comment: Yes, understood. What's the *issue*? Why can't you do that?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: Set an “enlarged” state and use that to drive a modal that displays the larger picture? There are essentially endless ways this could be done.